# IE11 - Unwanted spacing below select options

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is how it renders in IE. Take a look at the image

[image]

There's a lot of difference in how IE displays the select dropdown and Chrome. 
Here's the CSS i've used -

```
.newtopqtybtns select {
  font-family: "Gotham Book",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
}
```

I want IE to display the select dropdown like Chrome. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include the Html that's being rendered? Or post it as a snippet?

Comment: This is how IE renders an opened combo box. As a large list that includes at least the size of the combo box itself. Whereas Chrome and Firefox render them more traditionally as a list dropping below. I don't think you have that much control over that unless you recreate the select control in HTML and JS.

Comment: @Joey - Hmm. okay.